# "fastcgi_read_timeout" doesn't stop mysql queries

Tags: nginx, mysql

I have a problem with long mysql queries. My NGINX server has a line in fastcgi section to limit script execution:

```
server {
    location ~ \.php$ {
        <..>
        fastcgi_read_timeout 60; 
    }
}
```

but this ends only PHP file execution - mysql query continues for an unlimited time. Even one long query makes the server unresponsive and kills the website.

Since my mysql database has 100mil records I strictly need to also stop mysql query when the php file has been stopped.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Nginx has nothing to do with this. Configure your php/mysql. I guess there should be timeout option in php driver for mysql

Comment: I would also check mysql server settings and database schemas. Having a query take that long indicates design issues in database.

Comment: PHP and MySQL have no effective way to stop it either.  Find the query, present it to us, and provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  There may be an easy way to speed up the query.

Comment: some tables has 13mil records, so any query can make problems... If there isn't any easy way - it is also an answer for me to start look for other options...

Comment: Your table probably lacks proper indexes or your queries need to be optimized or both.